# Volume of a convex hull of 4 points in 3 dimension

Tags: discrete-mathematics, volume, divergence-operator, discrete-geometry

I have a problem to calculate the volume of the convex hull of 4 points $\in \mathbb{R}^3$. I've read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume
a formula that is resulted from the divergence theorem.

First one i can't see how it resulted from the divergence theorem.

Second, is there a more simple formula or algorithm to find the volume of the convex hull ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the volume of a tetrahedron. If the $4$ points are $P_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i)$, $i=1,4$, then the volume is $\frac{1}{6}$ of the absolute value of the determinant
$$ \left | \matrix{ 1 & x_1 & y_1 & z_1\\1 & x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\1 & x_3 & y_3 & z_3 \\ 1 & x_4 & y_4 & z_4 } \right | $$

Comment: Ok thanks, but can I see a book or notes of how one could conclude to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the volume of a 3-dimensional simplex.
If you have the 4 points $v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3$, the volume of the 3-dimensional simplex with these vertices is equal to
$$\left\lvert \frac{1}{3!} \det\left( \begin{array}{4} v_0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right) \right\rvert$$
See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume) for reference.
An equivalent formula for the volume of an $n$-dimensional simplex with vertices $v_0, \dots, v_n$ is:
$$ \left|{1\over n!} \det
 \begin{pmatrix}
  v_1-v_0, & v_2-v_0,& \dots, & v_n-v_0
 \end{pmatrix}\right|$$